# How to get contents of last fragment in the fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a master details pattern, list fragment at left of layout and in detail view(right side of layout) i have edit boxes and other fields for taking input from user. user can navigate by clicking on the tabs in list fragment to enter data for each section corresponding to list fragment.

I have a common object which holds the data given by user in all fragments and I have it in activity.

My doubt is when user navigate by clicking on list fragment how to get the data of last fragment and add to model(present in activity) before opening new fragment for the user

i have created a callback listerner in my activity which is called from list fragment oncilck.

can someone suggest this please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should save data into class and define it as `public static variable`.
or
create a object class to save all data, each fragment, fragment transfer this object.

Comment: @chan, my quesiton not regarding how to persist data in object, i want to know how to get data of previous fragment in the main activity if the user has clicked on the list fragment to navigate to other fragment... i have edited the question now..